# CKEditor config.stylesSet

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to get the dropdown styles option in CKEditor V4 configured. My test, shown below, does not work as expected. The dropdown style menu its self does display the "Green Check" option (label and the image used in the style) but its not applied to content of editor instance when used. I'm using the new inline editing feature (way cool it is too).

```
config.stylesSet = [
   { name: 'Green Check', element : 'ul li',
    styles :
    {
        'background' : 'url(/images/bullets/greencheck.png) no-repeat top left;',
        'list-style-type' : 'none;'  
    }
}

];
```

I specified the *element*  element : 'ul li', because 'ul' obviously targets the ul element but when 'li' is specified, I get nothing in the dropdown menu or applied to content.

Here's more or less the complete style that I'm trying to configure...

```
ul.greencheck li{
list-style-type:none;
line-height:18px;
background: url(/images/bullets/greencheck.png) no-repeat center left;
padding-left:30px;
}
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'ul li'` isn't a valid element, you can use either `'ul'` or '`li'` but not both

You should remove also the ending semicolon in the styles `'none;'` isn't valid, `'none'` is the correct one

and instead of setting the inline styles it would be better to just apply a class to the UL and leave the styles to a separate css file.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I do that with the class defined above?

Comment: ahh... the class is defined in the editor contents style sheet and the class name is appended to the element! (one of those days I think).